# Qt Creator doesn't forget old objects

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have the beginnings of a Qt GUI application created in the Qt Creator IDE. I used the project initially to show off some of the IDE's features, and in the process, I ended up adding a `QPushButton`, but I later removed it to start building the real program. I also used the "go to slot" feature to show that off as well, which created an entry in the `.ui` file which I removed after removing the button.

The issue then is, whenever I launch the program, I get the following error in my IDE console:

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pushButton_clicked()
```

All while the object `pushButton` does not exist anywhere in my code. I sent the project to a friend to load into his IDE, and the error was not present. I have no idea what's causing this, or if there's a cache I need to clear.

Comment: Are you sure that you removed the declaration and definition of on_pushButton_clicked() completely? If so try to delete all build files and rebuild your project.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I did.